# Ideal way to start Jetty when using Spring IoC, Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-boot, jetty

I am creating a new Spring application to hold a SOAP Web Service, and decided to use Jetty instead of deploying to Tomcat.

So far, the application doesn't have any Starter class and Spring is managing the creation of the Beans.

I am planning to have Jetty start up the Spring context, however I have also heard of Spring Boot which could possibly start Jetty, so which is best ?

I have the below configuration, which is used elsewhere to start Jetty such as this in a Starter class:

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("service-context.xml");
Server jetty = (Server) appContext.getBean("jettyServer");
```

However, I'm thinking this can be improved, and that I don't need a Starter class since Spring is creating everything. So, what is the best approach ? Thanks.

```
<bean id="jettyServer" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server" destroy-method="stop">

        <constructor-arg type="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ThreadPool">
            <bean id="ThreadPool" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
                <property name="minThreads" value="${jetty.min.threads}" />
                <property name="maxThreads" value="${jetty.max.threads}" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>

        <property name="connectors">
            <list>
                <bean id="Connector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
                    <constructor-arg ref="jettyServer"/>
                    <property name="port" value="${jetty.port}" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="handler">
            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
                <property name="handlers">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler">
                            <property name="contextPath" value="/" />
                            <property name="sessionHandler">
                                <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler" />
                            </property>
                            <property name="resourceBase" value="." />
                            <property name="servletHandler">
                                <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler">
                                    <property name="servlets"> <!-- servlet definition -->
                                        <list>
                                            <!-- default servlet -->
                                            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder">
                                                <property name="name" value="DefaultServlet" />
                                                <property name="servlet">
                                                    <!--<bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet"/> -->
                                                    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet" />
                                                </property>
                                                <property name="initParameters">
                                                    <map>
                                                        <entry key="contextConfigLocation" value="classpath*:**/spring-servlet.xml" />
                                                    </map>
                                                </property>
                                            </bean>
                                        </list>
                                    </property>
                                    <property name="servletMappings">
                                        <list><!-- servlet mapping -->
                                            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletMapping">
                                                <property name="pathSpecs">
                                                    <list>
                                                        <value>/</value>
                                                    </list>
                                                </property>
                                                <property name="servletName" value="DefaultServlet" />
                                            </bean>
                                        </list>
                                    </property>
                                </bean>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: With spring boot you would probably only have to include [`spring-boot-starter-jetty`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-use-jetty-instead-of-tomcat) and otherwise use [spring-boot-starter-ws](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/) to get SOAP running. Without writing extensive xml servlet configurations and other kind of configurations. That's what spring boot aims to simplify down to including the right starters.

Comment: Thanks, the spring-boot-starter-ws for SOAP says it only works for JDK 8 in the guide (too bad) so I'm using [Spring 3.2.4 Remoting](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/reference/remoting.html) . As for spring-boot-starter-jetty, I didn't know that there even was Tomcat embedded in Spring (support), so I'm unsure I'll go with Jetty as alternative, but how does this get started, I think i'll still have to write a simple starter class, it's hard to find a good guide or example for Spring 3.2.4.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-system-requirements.html - at least Java 7 should usually work out of the box. Not sure if -ws has special requirements but I guess the guide just doesn't mention that you could use EOL versions of java

Comment: I'm using Java 7, but could these Spring guys be so clueless, that in their latest guides they say JDK8 is required, for no reason at all ! Makes me very angry at this community due to the trouble faced to find a simple guide for a good integration with a *quite* recent Spring version (3.2.4 - August 07, 2013)